# MySQL SUM of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, sum

I wish to return a users details including the total number of votes a user has for all their events.

I have the following query which returns a list of users events and the number of events they have.

```
SELECT u.user_uid, u.firstname, u.lastname,
       ( SELECT COUNT(ev.event_vote_id) 
           FROM event_vote ev
           WHERE ue.event_uid = ev.event_uid
       ) AS votes,
       ( SELECT COUNT(ue.user_event_id) 
           FROM user_event ue
           WHERE ue.user_uid = u.user_uid
        ) AS no_of_events
FROM user_event ue
JOIN user u
ON u.user_uid = '1'
WHERE ue.user_uid = '1'
```

But it returns a record for every event they have and I need a SUM of the votes column.

**USER**

```
|  USER_UID  |  FIRSTNAME  |  LASTNAME  | 
       1         bob          smith
       2         rob          smithies 
       3         john         clark
```

**EVENT**

```
| GUID | NAME |  
  101   event1
  102   event2
  103   event3
```

**USER_EVENT**

```
| USER_EVENT_ID | USER_UID | EVENT_UID | 
       1001           1         101
       1002           2         102
       1003           1         103
```

**EVENT_VOTE**

```
| EVENT_VOTE_ID | USER_UID | EVENT_UID | 
       2001            2       101       
       2002            3       101
       2003            2       103
```

**Expected Result**

```
user_uid: 1
firstname: bob
lastname: smith
votes: 3        // 2 for 101, 1 for 103.
no_of_events: 2
```

Comment: Tip: Don't store 'ev', 'test', etc.

Comment: Thanks, I don't, thought it would make demo easier to read.

Comment: It doesn't. Using a different scale of integer would help however, e.g. 1,2,3, and 101,102,103, and 3010,3011,3012, that kind of thing. Also, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either join all tables and aggregate then:

```
select
  u.user_uid,
  u.firstname,
  u.lastname,
  count(*) as votes,
  count(distinct event_uid) as events
from user u
join user_event ue on ue.user_uid = u.user_uid
join event_vote ev on ev.event_uid = ue.event_uid
group by u.user_uid;
```

Or aggregate first and join then:

```
select
  u.user_uid,
  u.firstname,
  u.lastname,
  sums.votes,
  sums.events
from user u
left join
(
  select 
    ue.user_uid,
    count(*) as votes,
    count(distinct ev.event_uid) as events
  from user_event ue
  left join event_vote ev on ev.event_uid = ue.event_uid
  group by ue.user_uid
) sums on sums.user_uid = u.user_uid
```

If you want to select users without events or without votes, too, you need outer joins and `count(ev.event_vote_id)` instead of `count(*)`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I did make some minor changes though, i'll edit the answer to fit.

Comment: Actually I want to display all users. How do I add the outer joins?

Comment: Change `join` to `left join`. `JOIN` is short for `INNER JOIN`. `LEFT JOIN` is short for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Done. Thanks again.